# Appending sections in NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSource

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

I am attempting to create an `NSCollectionView` with a dynamic number of sections using `NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSource` and `NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayout`.

The collection view is used for displaying search results and the number of sections depends on the type and number of results found. Each section displays its content type using a different layout.

The data source is declared as `NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, SearchResult>` where `SearchResult` is a class implementing `Hashable` using `UUID()`. Sections with zero results are not empty, rather they don't exist in the collection view.

When my view controller is shown I clear existing search results:

```swift
func clearSearchResults(animate: Bool) {
    let snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, SearchResult>()
    dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animate)
}
```

When a search is performed I try to add a section to the collection view for each type of result found:

```swift
// Code that performs the search
var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, SearchResult>()

// If I append more than one section an exception is thrown in apply():
// snapshot.appendSections([ViewController.trackSection, ViewController.albumSection])

snapshot.appendSections([ViewController.trackSection])
snapshot.appendItems(tracks, toSection: ViewController.trackSection)

// This also causes an exception in apply():
// snapshot.appendSections([ViewController.albumSection])
// snapshot.appendItems(albums, toSection: ViewController.albumSection)

dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
```

The stack trace is:

```
2019-11-10 13:34:29.883728-0600 DiffableTest[64931:1820050] [General] An uncaught exception was raised
2019-11-10 13:34:29.883813-0600 DiffableTest[64931:1820050] [General] -[NSCollectionView insertSections:] Section index 1 out of bounds
2019-11-10 13:34:29.883937-0600 DiffableTest[64931:1820050] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff33a98f53 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff69b5e835 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff33a98da9 +[NSException raise:format:] + 189
    3   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff6469fd5b -[_NSCollectionViewCore insertSections:] + 267
    4   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff6465dd5e -[_NSDiffableDataSourceViewUpdater _performNSCollectionViewInsertUpdate:] + 222
    5   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff6465db33 -[_NSDiffableDataSourceViewUpdater _performViewUpdates:] + 594
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff3156d8e8 __58-[NSCollectionView performBatchUpdates:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 21
    7   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff646aabe5 -[_NSCollectionViewCore _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:] + 323
    8   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff646aaa7f -[_NSCollectionViewCore _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:] + 90
    9   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff646aaa02 -[_NSCollectionViewCore _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:] + 74
    10  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff646aa957 -[_NSCollectionViewCore performBatchUpdates:completion:] + 53
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff3156d7f4 -[NSCollectionView performBatchUpdates:completionHandler:] + 282
    12  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff6465d2ee -[_NSDiffableDataSourceViewUpdater _performUpdateWithCollectionViewUpdateItems:dataSourceSnapshotter:updateHandler:completion:] + 528
    13  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff646c72a2 -[__NSDiffableDataSource _commitNewDataSource:withViewUpdates:completion:] + 265
    14  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff646c1cb9 __66-[__NSDiffableDataSource applyDifferencesFromSnapshot:completion:]_block_invoke.259 + 190
    15  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff646c1fd2 __66-[__NSDiffableDataSource applyDifferencesFromSnapshot:completion:]_block_invoke.284 + 170
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010039e78f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001003af4cb _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 135
    18  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff646c172d -[__NSDiffableDataSource applyDifferencesFromSnapshot:completion:] + 842
    19  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff64765417 +[_NSUIAnimator performWithAnimation:] + 90
    20  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff646c2939 -[__NSDiffableDataSource applyDifferencesFromSnapshot:animatingDifferences:completion:] + 158
    21  libswiftAppKit.dylib                0x00007fff6a2f6bb3 $s6AppKit34NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSourceC5apply_20animatingDifferences10completionyAA010NSDiffablefG8SnapshotVyxq_G_SbyycSgtF + 211
    22  DiffableTest                        0x0000000100005c73 $s12DiffableTest14ViewControllerC13performSearchyyyXlSgF + 3059
```

Am I misusing the API in some way?

See https://github.com/sbooth/DiffableTest for an example project.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Are you using pure Swift structs/classes for your identifiers or are you using `NSObject` derived classes like in the sample code? There's been some confusion around using pure Swift entities on macOS because `NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSource` was only introduced in 10.15.1 (without any documentation or release notes). Using the referenced based API works for me, but I also get out-of-bounds exception using the pure Swift API under 10.15.3.

Comment: @kennyc I never got things working quite like I wanted/expected. I am using pure Swift. From what I've gathered `NSCollectionView` has bugs with appending sections and moving items. It's possible to make things work by calling `apply()` after essentially each operation (step updates) and always having at least one section.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I've got a report in with DTS (again) to try and better understanding `NSCollectionView` and diffable data sources. I can get it working using the `Reference` based APIs, which require the use of `NSObject` derived identifiers, but attempting to use Swift classes, structs or enums always results in an index out-of-bounds exception being thrown, even if I basically use the sample code from WWDC.

Answer (score 2):

I have found it is *sometimes* necessary to call `apply(_:animatingDifferences:)` twice, once after calling `appendSection(_:)` with animation `false`, and once after calling `appendItems(_:)`.

For example:

```
extension AnimalsViewController {
    enum Section {
        case main
    }

    private func makeDataSource() -> UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Section, String> {
        UITableViewDiffableDataSource(tableView: tableView) { tableView, indexPath, name in
            let cell = tableView
                .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier.animalCell.rawValue,
                                     for: indexPath)

            cell.textLabel?.text = name
            return cell
        }
    }

    private func update() {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, String>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
        snapshot.appendItems(viewModel.animalNames)
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is similar to what Apple DTS advised, but collection views on iOS and macOS are quite different so it's too bad if iOS has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

After some brief testing on my part, the section index out-of-bounds exception appears to be thrown when the data source applies the snapshot using animation. If you disable the animations when modifying any of the sections, then the exception doesn't appear to be thrown. (At least not in my basic tests.)

The following code *appears* to be working properly for me:

```
let outgoingSectionCount = dataSource.numberOfSections(in:collectionView)
let incomingSectionCount = snapshot.sectionIdentifiers.count

let shouldAnimate  = true
let canAnimate     = outgoingSectionCount == incomingSectionCount

dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences:(shouldAnimate && canAnimate)
```

YMMV...

**Follow-Up**

As you elude to in your comment above, Apple DTS recommends calling `dataSource.apply(...)` after you've appended the sections but before you've appended any items. Once the sections have been successfully inserted, you should then be able to insert the items and call `dataSource.apply(...)` a second time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some bugs related to `NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSource` has been solved in macOS 11. Applying snapshots with animations that crashed in macOS 10.15.*, seems to work in most cases in macOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the vexing issue myself. The only reliable fix was invalidating the layout before the application of the snapshot.

```
if snapshot.sectionIdentifiers.isEmpty {
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}

dataSource.apply(snapshot, ...)
```